# Printing multiple pages with canvas functions LineTo and Textout

Tags: canvas, printing, lazarus

How can you print multiple pages using the print canvas. With lineto and textout to produce the output on the canvas?  The canvas works fine on a single page.  This is using the normal print for the first page.  Then used copyrect to the printer canvas and issued a new page but the subsequent pages are blank.  I saw in one question they were talking about a PrintPage I didn't see a function or method like this with Lazarus.  Here is some code I don't know if it is helpful.

```
          kBracketTree: with TestTableForSpeciesData, Printer.Canvas do
      begin
        intCPLngth := Origin.ttoBracket.Height * 5;
        intCPWdth := Origin.ttoBracket.Width * 5;
        if imgPrintView.Canvas = nil then
          imgPrintView.Canvas.Create;
        imgPrintView.Height := intCPLngth; // * 6 div 5;
        imgPrintView.Width := intCPWdth; // * 6 div 5;
        intVPages := intCPLngth div intHeight + 1;
        intHPages := intCPWdth div intWidth + 1;
        DrawScale(dblScale);
        DrawBracket(HomeVrtcl);
        DrawBracketLabel(Species[NodeCount].VrtclPosition, Species[NodeCount].EndSegment);
        DrawBracketLabel(Species[NodeCount - 1].VrtclPosition, Species[NodeCount - 1].EndSegment);
        intNdLvl := 1;
        while boolMoreNodeLevels(intNdLvl) do
        begin
          for inx := 0 to NodeCount - 2 do
            if Species[inx].NodeLevel = intNdLvl then
              DrawBracketLabel(Species[inx].VrtclPosition, Species[inx].EndSegment);
          inc(intNdLvl);
        end;
        if boolBootStrap then
          for inx := SpeciesCount to NodeCount do
            DrawBootStrapLabel(Species[inx].VrtclPosition, BSPercent[inx - SpeciesCount], 5, 5, 55);
        if (intVPages > 1) or (intHPages > 1) then
        begin
          if intVPages > 1 then
            if intHPages = 1 then
            begin
              intVStart := 2;
              intHStart := 1;
            end
            else
            begin
              intVStart := 1;
              intHStart := 2;
            end
          else
          begin
            intVStart := 1;
            intHStart := 2;
          end;
          for iny := intVStart to intVPages do
          begin
            Pen.Color := clBlack;
            Brush.Style := bsSolid;
            Brush.Color := clWhite;
            Clear;
            with rctPrnt do
            begin
              Left := 0;
              Top := 0;
              if intCPLngth > intHeight * iny then
                Bottom := intHeight - 1
              else
                Bottom := intCPLngth - intHeight * (iny - 1) - 1;
            end;
            with rctSlctd do
            begin
              Top := intHeight * (iny - 1);
              if intCPLngth > intHeight * iny then
                Bottom := intHeight * iny - 1
              else
                Bottom := intCPLngth;
            end;
            for inx := intHStart to intHPages do
            begin
              NewPage;
              with rctPrnt do
                if intCPWdth > intWidth * inx then
                  Right := intWidth - 1
                else
                  Right := intCPWdth - intWidth * (inx - 1) - 1;
              with rctSlctd do
              begin
                Left := intWidth * (inx - 1);
                if intCPWdth > intWidth * inx then
                  Right := intWidth * inx - 1
                else
                  Right := intCPWdth - 1;
              end;
              Canvas.Rectangle(0, 0, intWidth - 1, intHeight - 1);
              Canvas.CopyRect(rctPrnt, imgPrintView.Canvas, rctSlctd);
              Canvas.Refresh;
            end;
            intHStart := 1;
          end;
        end;
```

Comment: Produce a MCVE that prints a single word of text, starts new page, and does it again. We don't want to wade through all that code. Simplify.

Answer (score 0):

In Lazarus the TPrinter class has a method called NewPage. In Lazarus ctrl-click a TPrinter declaration to see all the methods available in the source code.

Comment: I got the MCVE to work by drawing four rectangles on the bit map.  I put a design inside the rectangles such as lines, squares, and triangles.  Then I was able to draw each rectangle on a separate page with a copyrect on the printer's canvas issuing a newpage after first page.  I changed the original program and discover I create and cast the bit map to set the height and width for canvas.  I now have it printing a black rectangle on each page.  I'll have to test changing the brushes and/or pens.  But know I created a new problem when it creates an image.  continued....

Comment: The printable image is 5 times the size of the original image.  If it get very large at all I'm getting #203 errors.  Thanks for your support juus and David Heffernan